# How to install PyTorch in Coral Dev Board

Tags: pytorch, google-coral

I was trying to install PyTorch in [Coral Dev Board](https://coral.ai/products/dev-board/). I could not find any online reference for the installation.

- Can I install PyTorch Mobile (formerly Lite) in Coral Dev Board?
- Does the architecture support the installation?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert on pytorch but I don't believe they currently have any releases for arm platforms. Although people has been able to build it from source and get it working on arm platforms like jetson nano. This is probably the best guide that you can follow or based from in order figure out the installation:
https://gist.github.com/dusty-nv/ef2b372301c00c0a9d3203e42fd83426

I modified it slightly to fit the dev board but haven't tried yet:

```
# clone pyTorch repo
git clone http://github.com/pytorch/pytorch
cd pytorch
git submodule update --init --recursive

# install prereqs
sudo pip3 install -U setuptools
sudo pip3 install -r requirements.txt

# Develop Mode:
python3 setup.py install
```

FYI, I do want to mention that the edgetpu is specialized for processing tflite tensor only. I just wanted to make sure you know that before going through with the installation and realized that there isn't any performance boost when using the pytorch API.

Comment: Also, if you decided to install, I would add swap space and sdcard storage, just in case.

Comment: Thanks a lot Nam Vu. Will try my luck with this.

Comment: I'm trying to do the same, how your experience? and will https://github.com/pytorch/xla help in running pytorch model on the coral devboard TPU?